# How to access data and handle missing data in a dictionaries within a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given, df:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data =\
{'Col1': [1, 2, 3],
 'Person': [{'ID': 10001,
   'Data': {'Address': {'Street': '1234 Street A',
     'City': 'Houston',
     'State': 'Texas',
     'Zip': '77002'}},
   'Age': 30,
   'Income': 50000},
  {'ID': 10002,
   'Data': {'Address': {'Street': '7892 Street A',
     'City': 'Greenville',
     'State': 'Maine',
     'Zip': np.nan}},
   'Age': np.nan,
   'Income': 63000},
  {'ID': 10003, 'Data': {'Address': np.nan}, 'Age': 56, 'Income': 85000}]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Input Dataframe:

```
   Col1                                                                                                                                            Person
0     1  {'ID': 10001, 'Data': {'Address': {'Street': '1234 Street A', 'City': 'Houston', 'State': 'Texas', 'Zip': '77002'}}, 'Age': 30, 'Income': 50000}
1     2  {'ID': 10002, 'Data': {'Address': {'Street': '7892 Street A', 'City': 'Greenville', 'State': 'Maine', 'Zip': nan}}, 'Age': nan, 'Income': 63000}
2     3                                                                               {'ID': 10003, 'Data': {'Address': nan}, 'Age': 56, 'Income': 85000}
```

My expected output dataframe is `df[['Col1', 'Income', 'Age', 'Street', 'Zip']]` where Income, Age, Street, and Zip come from within Person:

```
   Col1  Income   Age         Street    Zip
0     1   50000  30.0  1234 Street A  77002
1     2   63000   NaN  7892 Street A    nan
2     3   85000  56.0            NaN    nan
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using list comprehension, we can create most of these columns.

```
df['Income'] = [x.get('Income') for x in df['Person']]
df['Age'] = [x.get('Age') for x in df['Person']]
df['Age']
```

Output:

```
0    30.0
1     NaN
2    56.0
Name: Age, dtype: float64
```

However, dealing with np.nan values inside a nested dictionary is a real pain. Let's look at getting data from a nested dictionary data where one of the values is nan.

```
df['Street'] = [x.get('Data').get('Address').get('Street') for x in df['Person']]
```

We get an AttributeError:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-80-cc2f92bfe95d> in <module>
      1 #However, let's look at getting data rom a nested dictionary where one of the values is nan.
      2 
----> 3 df['Street'] = [x.get('Data').get('Address').get('Street') for x in df['Person']]
      4 
      5 #We get and AttributeError because NoneType object has no get method

<ipython-input-80-cc2f92bfe95d> in <listcomp>(.0)
      1 #However, let's look at getting data rom a nested dictionary where one of the values is nan.
      2 
----> 3 df['Street'] = [x.get('Data').get('Address').get('Street') for x in df['Person']]
      4 
      5 #We get and AttributeError because NoneType object has no get method

AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Let's use the `.str` accessor with dictionary keys to fetch this data.
There is little documentation in pandas that shows how you can use `.str.get` or `.str[]` to fetch values from dictionary objects in a dataframe column/pandas series.

```
df['Street'] = df['Person'].str['Data'].str['Address'].str['Street']
```

Output:

```
0    1234 Street A
1    7892 Street A
2              NaN
Name: Street, dtype: object
```

And, likewise with

```
df['Zip'] = df['Person'].str['Data'].str['Address'].str['Zip']
```

Leaving us with the columns to build the desired dataframe
`df[['Col1', 'Income', 'Age', 'Street', 'Zip']]`
from dictionaries.

Output:

```
   Col1  Income   Age         Street    Zip
0     1   50000  30.0  1234 Street A  77002
1     2   63000   NaN  7892 Street A    NaN
2     3   85000  56.0            NaN    NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Col1": [1, 2, 3],
    "Person": [
        {
            "ID": 10001,
            "Data": {
                "Address": {
                    "Street": "1234 Street A",
                    "City": "Houston",
                    "State": "Texas",
                    "Zip": "77002",
                }
            },
            "Age": 30,
            "Income": 50000,
        },
        {
            "ID": 10002,
            "Data": {
                "Address": {
                    "Street": "7892 Street A",
                    "Zip": np.nan,
                    "City": "Greenville",
                    "State": "Maine",
                }
            },
            "Age": np.nan,
            "Income": 63000,
        },
        {
            "ID": 10003,
            "Data": {"Address": np.nan},
            "Age": 56, "Income": 85000
        },
    ],
})


row_dic_list = df.to_dict(orient='records') # convert to dict 

# remain = ['Col1', 'Income', 'Age', 'Street', 'Zip']  
new_row_dict_list = []
# Iterate over each row to generate new data
for row_dic in row_dic_list: 
    col1 = row_dic['Col1']
    person_dict = row_dic['Person']

    age = person_dict['Age']
    income = person_dict['Income']
    address = person_dict["Data"]["Address"]
    street = np.nan
    zip_v = np.nan
    if isinstance(address, dict):
        street = address["Street"]
        zip_v = address["Zip"]
    new_row_dict = {
        'Col1': col1,
        'Income': income,
        'Age': age,
        'Street': street,
        'Zip': zip_v,
    }
    new_row_dict_list.append(new_row_dict)
# Generate a dataframe from each new row of data
new_df = pd.DataFrame(new_row_dict_list)
print(new_df)

"""
   Col1  Income   Age         Street    Zip
0     1   50000  30.0  1234 Street A  77002
1     2   63000   NaN  7892 Street A    NaN
2     3   85000  56.0            NaN    NaN

"""
```